# Converter formato de data

Tags: php

Galera,
Preciso converter o formato de dados dos campos do meu formulário para gravação no meu banco. Como os dados estão vindos do formulário por array não estou conseguindo capturá-los e converte antes de gravar.
O campo data está no meu formulário identificado como "**vencimento[]**" e com mascara no formato *00/00/0000* daí quando receber preciso convertê-lo para *0000/00/00*.
O campo valor está no meu formulário como "**valor[]**" com mascara de moeda *1.000,00* mas preciso convertê-lo para *1000.00*.
Já tentei fazer a conversão antes e também dentro do laço mas dá erro.

```
$valorparc = $_POST['valor'];
    $data_vctoparcela = $_POST['vencimento'];
    $quant_linhas = count($_POST['valor']);
   for ($i=0; $i<$quant_linhas; $i++) {
       $data = $data_vctoparcela[$i];
       $valorp = $valorparc[$i];
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO lc_parcelas (ID,cod_cliente,id_fatura,valor_parcela,data_vcto,parcela)
            VALUES('".$idEMP."','".$cod_cliente."','".$id_fatura."','".$valorp."','".$data."','".$i."')") or die (mysql_error());
    }
```

Comment: especifique o forma de forma adequada.. Não dá para saber o que é 00/00  .. O trecho 0000, por dedução é o ano. Mas qual a posição do mês e do dia? Exemplo yyyy/mm/dd

Comment: no formulario: dd/mm/yyyy mas no mysql tem que gravar yyyy/mm/dd

Comment: no mysql, normalmente usa o padrão iso8601 yyyy-mm-dd.. mas dependendo da versão também aceita / (barra)

Comment: no formulário, o usuário insere a data livremente? é um campo do tipo input text?  é mais seguro e simples  definir um campo tipo select para dia, outro para mês e outro para ano.

Comment: Opa brother não sei se vai servir pra vc !!! mais da uma olhada se vc consegue implementar essa classe ao seu código !! [Link da Classe da uma olhada aqui !](http://www.montepage.com.br/coisas-legais-para-site/formatar-data-hora-moeda-cnpj-cpf-numero-telefone-cep-tudo-que-quiser#conteudo)

Comment: Daniel, desculpe meu erro, no mysql é yyyy-mm-dd mesmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia fazer da seguinte forma isso para formatar os campos:

```
<?php

//Formatar data
$data = '11/20/2015';

$dataParts = array_reverse(explode('/', $data));
//echo implode('/', $dataParts);//01/11/2015
//Para gravação no banco de dados certamente deve ser dessa forma
echo implode('-', $dataParts);//01-11-2015


echo '<br>';

//Formatar moeda
$morney = '1.000,00';
$newMorney = str_replace(array('.', ','), array('', '.'), $morney);
echo number_format($newMorney, 2, '.', '');//1000.00
```

No seu código poderia ficar da seguinte forma:

```
$valorparc = $_POST['valor'];
$data_vctoparcela = $_POST['vencimento'];
$quant_linhas = count($_POST['valor']);

for ($i = 0; $i < $quant_linhas; $i++) {

  $dataParts = array_reverse(explode('/', $data_vctoparcela[$i]));
  $data = implode('-', $dataParts);//01/11/2015

  $newMorney = str_replace(array('.', ','), array('', '.'), $valorparc[$i]);
  $valorp = number_format($newMorney, 2, '.', '');//1000.00

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO lc_parcelas (ID, cod_cliente, id_fatura, valor_parcela, data_vcto, parcela) VALUES('$idEMP','$cod_cliente','$id_fatura','$valorp','$data','$i')")
  or die (mysql_error());

}
```

Comment: @yure_pereira , obrigado pela ajuda, perfeito. **RESOLVIDO**, obrigado a todos pela valiosa ajuda

Answer (score 0):

aqui tens php é bom :)
fazes um explode a string original depois contactas tudo e formas uma unica string  ou em entao em java script.

```
<?php
    $str = 'one,two,three,four';
    // zero limit
    print_r(explode(',',$str,0));
    print "<br>";
    // positive limit
    print_r(explode(',',$str,2));
    print "<br>";
    // negative limit 
    print_r(explode(',',$str,-1));
?>
```